Kodak's h263 MOV files - letterboxed on playback - how to force editors & VLC to use "width" instead of "original width"?
I found a lot of family movies in my old Kodak DX6340 digital camera. Unfortunately, none of the editors (Filmora, Davinci, Movavi, MovieMaker) or any player (except Apple QuickTime Player) can display them correctly - the bar always appears on the right and at the bottom:

I spent many hours looking for the reason and it seems to me that it is because:

Kodak used H263 as the codec H263 codec has a native (one of many)
resolution of 352x288 (does not support 320x240)
Kodak in its camera specifications: (Camera Manual) states that the
videos are 320x240 and that is how they are played when I connect the
camera to a TV with a cable or when I play them on my computer using
QuickTime Player:

The MediaInfo application gives the same size:

And now the most important thing: MediaInfo gives the following data:

With/Height = 320/240, Original Width/Original height = 352/288, Display aspect Ratio = 4:3 So, when I try to open this MOV in movie editors or players - those applications look at the wrong parameters. They should look at 320/240 and 4:3. And they look at 352x288 (additionally - it is not 4:3!) so then they artificially draw this black bar on the right and at the bottom.

Is there any way to force the appropriate interpretation on the MOV header? For example, by modifying this header somehow? If anyone would like to see it on their own, I am attaching this MOV file: link 1
Please do not let me crop/resize the MOV, it has only 320x240, I don't want to lose details (if I can say that 320x240 could have details...;-) ) and do not want to deform (stretch) the picture.
